# feedback sent callback uservoice

Tags: javascript, callback, uservoice

I want to do some custom action once feedback or any info is submitted using UserVoice Widget.

Is there a callback event available for the same?

Also, I intend to use multiple UserVoice widgets in single page. It doesn't seem to work somehow.

1. I need to redirect the user to a different page once he submits the feedback in UserVoice. For that, some kind of callback from UserVoice is expected to trigger the desired action.
2. When I use 2 widgets in a page, it overrides the existing properties and picks up the default options for the second widget.

Comment: My opinion is, correct reason to put on hold is required. I have seen Uservoice and worked with it. AFAIK it is not too broad and not many solutions (Not a single) is available. People who closed it, may be need to reconsider their decision on this question.

Comment: I have an answer to my question and it was not broad. Only if I could add an answer